# Have rspec ignore missing template error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm writing specs for controllers in a plugin. The views for the corresponding controllers/actions are in the main app, so running the controller specs results in a missing template error. Is it possible to have rpsec ignore the missing template error or not search for the view?

Answer (score 0):

Currently rspec-rails does not allow to disable missing template errors in controller specs. There is an option to disable view rendering in controller specs but in any case templates must exists as described in [rspec docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-1/docs/controller-specs/do-not-render-views)

It was possible in rspec-rails 1.X though